# questions on LYAH's implementation of take

Tags: haskell

I've been trying to learn haskell with the book Learn yourself a haskell. The book covers an implementation of `take` in the following way:

```
take' :: (Num i, Ord i) => i -> [a] -> [a]  
take' n _  
    | n <= 0   = []  
take' _ []     = []  
take' n (x:xs) = x : take' (n-1) xs
```

I have two questions on this code:

1. In the function declaration why are we using the same letter `i` to declare `(Num i, Ord i)`? Does this not overwrite the fact that `i` is of type `Num` with `i` is of type `Ord`?
2. I want to modify `take'` so that if n is larger than length of the list a message is printed out. I've tried to implement this by using the function length in the definition for take' but then the function fails to load:

   take' n _

   ```
       | n > length _ = print "n greater than length of list"
   ```

Comment: If an error message needs to be printed, it's best to leave that up to the *caller* of `take'`. The function should simply encode the possibility of an error in its return type; some examples would be `Int -> [a] -> Maybe [a]`, `Int -> [a] -> Either String [a]`, and `Int -> [a] -> Either TakeError [a]`, where `TakeError` is some custom type that enumerates the possible errors, rather than a fixed string *description* of the error.

Comment: @chepner I'd say that only makes sense for _recoverable_ errors. But if you wanted to say "it is an error to use this function this way" I don't think it makes a lot of sense to encode this in the type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In the function declaration why are we using the same letter i to declare (Num i, Ord i)? Does this not overwrite the fact that i is of type Num with i is of type Ord?

This is not a type declaration, but a type *constraint*. This means "`i` is some type that is both a number and orderable" (you  can have numbers that aren't orderable and orderable things that aren't numbers).

> | n > length _ = print "n greater than length of list"

That doesn't work because `_` is a wildcard pattern - the list parameter is not actually bound to anything. Writing `_` in a pattern means "I know there's something that's supposed to go there, but I don't care what it is". If you want to use the list there you'll have to give it a name.

(Hint: You don't need to calculate the length of the list - there's another case where you can check if the caller tried to take more elements out of the list than intended)

(Hint 2: `print "n greater than length of list"` won't work there as it's of type `IO ()` rather than `[a]` - remember that the function still needs to return the right type! If you think some input is invalid and want to print an error message and terminate your program you can use the `error` function instead).

Answer (score 1):

> 1. In the function declaration why are we using the same letter `i` to declare `(Num i, Ord i)`? Does this not overwrite the fact that `i` is of type `Num` with `i` is of type `Ord`?

First, let's point out the main misunderstanding. `Num` is not a type. `Ord` is not a type. Consequently, `i` can not have type `Num` or `Ord`.

Instead, `i` stands for a generic, unknown type, to be determined when `take'` is called. At call-time, `i` could be `Int`, `Integer`, or `Float`, to mention a few.

In principle, the caller can choose any type they want. However, the constraint `(Num i, Ord i)` means that the caller must choose a type `i` which satisfies `Num i` (i.e. it is a numeric type), and `Ord i` (i.e. it is also an ordered type). These two constraints complement each other: complex nubmers are numeric, but not ordered, the boolean type is ordered, but not numeric.

So, there is no contradiction between these constraints.

Answer (score 1):

> In the function declaration why are we using the same letter `i` to declare `(Num i, Ord i)`? Does this not overwrite the fact that i is of type `Num` with `i` is of type `Ord`?

This is a *type constraint*. It means that the type `i` needs to offer the functions defined by the `Num` (or `Ord`) typeclass. If you write multiple typeclasses with the same type (here `i`), it thus means that `i` needs to be an instance of all these typeclasses (and thus implement the functions that both typeclasses declare). For this specific example, it means that `i` must be a type such that `(<=) :: Ord i => i -> i -> i` exists as well as a `(-) :: Num i => i -> i -> i`. If you would omit one of the two, then `n <= 0` or `n-1` can no longer be evaluated, since it is no longer guaranteed that these functions exist.

> I want to modify take' so that if n is larger than length of the list a message is printed out. I've tried to implement this by using the function length in the definition for take' but then the function fails to load.

Well the idea of Haskell is that `print` has `IO ()`. If you write `print` you do *not* print. It basically means that you have *encapsulated* this `IO` action. You can thus pass that around, and for example use it in the `main` to actually print something. But nevertheless, it conflicts with the output type `[a]`. You can however for example use `trace` here as some sort of debugging to perform an *unsafe* `IO` action. For ecample:

```
import Debug.Trace

take' :: (Num i, Ord i) => i -> [a] -> [a]  
take' n _  
    | n <= 0   = []  
take' n [] | n > 0 = trace "n greater than length of list" []
           | otherwise = []  
take' n (x:xs) = x : take' (n-1) xs
```

But this is used for *debugging* purposes. The idea of Haskell is to have a declarative language. As a result you specify *what* you want to return, not much *how* you want that to happen, and which actions need to be taken.